# tokenizer in spark dataframe API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

Each row of a Spark dataframe `df` contains a tab-separated string in a column `rawFV`.  I already know that splitting on the tab will yield an `array of 3 strings` for all the rows.  This can be verified by:

```
df.map(row => row.getAs[String]("rawFV").split("\t").length != 3).filter(identity).count()
```

and making sure that the count is indeed `0`.

My question is: How to do this using the pipeline API?

Here's what I tried:

```
val tabTok = new RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("rawFV").setOutputCol("tk").setPattern("\t")
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tabTok))
val transf = pipeline.fit(df)
val df2 = transf.transform(df)
df2.map(row => row.getAs[Seq[String]]("tk").length != 3).filter(identity).count()
```

which is NOT equal to `0`.

The issue has to do with the presence of missing values.  For example:

[image: example]

The pipeline code with `RegexTokenizer` would return 3 fields on the first line but only 2 on the second.  On the other hand, the first code would correctly return 3 fields everywhere.

Comment: It would be much more useful if you provide example data which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is related to the presence of missing values.  For example, if you have a tab-separated file like this:  "a\ta\ta\nb\t\tb".  I would get 3 fields on the first line but only 2 in the second

Comment: Could add this to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an expected behavior. By default `minTokenLength` parameter is equal to 1 to avoid empty strings in the output. If you want to return empty strings it should be set to 0.

```
new RegexTokenizer()
  .setInputCol("rawFV")
  .setOutputCol("tk")
  .setPattern("\t")
  .setMinTokenLength(0)
```